# How to write GraphQL schema, query and mutation for nested mongodb document

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Below is my mongodb document

```
{
    field1: "Value 1",
    field2: 123
    field3: {
        actual: {
            startAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z",
            endAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z"
        },
        planned: {
            startAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z",
            endAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z"
        }
    },
    field4: {
        actual: {
            startAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z",
            endAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z"
        },
        planned: {
            startAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z",
            endAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z"
        }
    },
    field5: {
        actual: {
            startAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z",
            endAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z"
        },
        planned: {
            startAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z",
            endAt: "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write typeDef, query and mutation for the above document. I am using Apollo Server for Express. I am new to graphql so little confused about **how to write optimized graphql types as the documents fields (field3, field4, field5) are nested objects**.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, but it depends on your resolvers:

```
type Query {
fields:[Field]
}

 type Mutation {
createField(input:FieldInput!):Field
}

type Field {
  actual:Time
  planned:Time
}

input FieldInput {
  actual:TimeInput
  planned:TimeInput
 }

 type Time {
  startAt:String
  endAt:String
 }

 input TimeInput {
  startAt:String
  endAt:String
 }
```

- note that this is created for .graphql file, so if you want to generate the schema using only javascript you might have to refactor it